# Bloquear requisição que contenha determinado elemento no cabeçalho usando Nginx

Tags: nginx

Olá,

Vamos supor que uma requisição possui o elemento HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP no cabeçalho. Esse elemento é incluído pelo CloudFlare.

Como faço para bloquear todas as requisições que tiverem esse elemento no Nginx?

Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    ...

    deny $http_cf_connecting_ip;
}
```

Imaginei que dessa forma o Nginx iria pegar o IP que está sendo armazenado em $http_cf_connecting_ip e o bloquearia, resolvendo meu caso. Mas não funcionou e gerou o seguinte erro:

```
[emerg] 402#402: invalid parameter "$http_cf_connecting_ip" in ...
```

Também tentei da seguinte forma:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    ...

    if ($http_cf_connecting_ip) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

E o Nginx me retorna outro erro:

```
[emerg] 278#278: "deny" directive is not allowed here in ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foquei tanto no deny que acabei esquecendo que posso forçar um retorno juntamente com um código qualquer, encerrando a requisição.

A solução pra quem tiver o mesmo problema é o seguinte:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    ...

    if ($http_cf_connecting_ip) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```